# How to approximate function for geometrically growing sequence?

Tags: python, math, curve-fitting, periodic

I have the function to create `x0`:

```
x0 = []
    for i in range(0,N):
        if i == 0:
            a =  0.4
        else:
            a = round(0.4 + 0.3*2**(i-1), 1)
        print(i, a)
        x0.append(a)
```

which gives me data of growing sequence: `[0.4, 0.7, 1.0, 1.6, 2.8, 5.2, 10.0, 19.6, 38.8, 77.2, ...]` which I want to find a function to fit to these points. I don't want to use polynomials because the `N` can be different but need to find single parameter function. The projection needs to be very general.

My approach is using the code:

```
def fun(x, a, b):    
    return np.cos(x**(2/3) * a + b) 
    
# Make fit #
y0 = [0]*len(x0)
p, c = curve_fit(f=fun, xdata=np.array(x0), ydata=y0)
  
x = np.linspace(0, max(x0), 10000)    
plt.plot(x, fun(x, *p))    
plt.scatter(x0, y0)
```

That function's progress seem to be too wide for starting points and quite fit the last ones. I also tried to lower the initial oscillations by multiplying this function by `x`, but the period still is too wide at the beginning. Is it possible to find good oscillation function to go thru (almost) all those points? I don't know how to set parameter under the `x**(...)` because placing there a variable cause the fit to estimate it as close to 1, which is not what I need. Can I set the power for `sin(x**b)` that way? If not what functions family should I try?

Below the plot for function multiplied by `b*x`. The oscillations at first points should be much denser.
[image]

Comment: Not sure id I really get what you want, but `sin( pi * ( log2( ( x - a ) / b ) + 1  )  )` gets close.

Comment: note. in this sense the i==0 should be 0.4 +0.3/2 = 0.55

Comment: @mikuszefski Yes, it's close. This function is mad in the beginning but I guess I can cut it somehow. The first point is not very important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to suggestions I've found the best fit and I think it can't be better.

The solution is:

```
 def fun(x, a, b, c):
        return np.cos(np.pi*(np.log2((x-a)/b) + c))
```

and the fit method looks like

```
p, c = curve_fit(f=fun, xdata=np.array(x0), ydata=y0, bounds=([0, -np.inf, -np.inf], [x0[0], np.inf, np.inf]))
```

It's important to set initial bounds for `a` to avoid convergention failure or "Residuals are not finite in the initial point" issues. At last each point has its own crossing despite mad behavior of the close to 0 at the domain. Parameters are pretty close to 0 or 1 - not tending to infinity.